# build onclick inside a loop Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do:

dynamically build a onclick event attached to an img tag and pass 3 values. The problem is that the onclick is within a loop so the value of the passed values change depending on their position within the loop.

I have managed to get one value passed by attaching it to the img id, but im at a loss as to how to pass the other two

```
newElement.innerHTML = '<img id="'+ id + '" class="Videoimg" onclick="myFunction(this.id,\"" + VideoTitlePlayer + "\","' + VideodescPlayer + '")" src="' + thumbnail +'"><div id="VideoNames" class="VideoTitle">'+ title +'<br><div class="VideoDescription">' + desc + '</div></div>';
```

OK so this is the issue
This function is called to build a menu of youtube videos

```
$.each(playlistVideoItems, function (index, item) 
            {
            displayVideoResult(item.snippet, item.snippet.resourceId.videoId);
            });
```

---

```
function displayVideoResult(videoSnippet, VideoPlay) 
{ var title = videoSnippet.title;
var desc = videoSnippet.description;
var thumbnail = videoSnippet.thumbnails.default.url;
var id = VideoPlay;

var newElement = document.createElement("div");
newElement.setAttribute("class", "VideoContainerCSS");
    // Set the value to what you want
  newElement.innerHTML = '<img id="'+ id + '" class="Videoimg" onclick="myFunction(this.id)" src="' + thumbnail +'"><div id="VideoNames" class="VideoTitle">'+ title +'<br><div class="VideoDescription">' + desc + '</div></div>';

document.getElementById("results").appendChild(newElement);
}
```

I need some way to build into the link the videoID, video Title and Video desc so when the img link is clicked it passes all 3 to a function that runs the youtube api

Comment: Maybe you should post the entire loop, so we can understand what you're talking about ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use data-id, data-video-title, data-other-prop etc. then `onclick="myFunction(this.dataset, ...`

Comment: tried this but when this.data-video-title and data-other-prop are referenced in the onclick its not firing,

Comment: completly my fault I was trying to pass the values, took your soluction and instead of passing this.dataset I just passed the whole object **onclick="myFunction(this.dataset)"** and works a treat,

Thanks Alot

Seamus

Answer (score 1):

Since you have jQuery, you can avoid using `onclick` and use a jQuery selector and event handler.

Once you have created the elements, use a jQuery selector to capture them. Better yet, use one on the container that uses a delegated event style.

You might need to change the markup just a bit to get the strings, though.

```
$('.container').on('click', 'img', function(e) {
  var $el = $(this);
  myFunction(this.id, $el.find('.VideoTitle').text(), $el.find('. VideoDescription').text());
});
```

Using this format you can create one event handler that supports all your elements.

Comment: jquery isnt my first language lol but how will this allow me to build the menu with each title and desc?

Comment: @SeamusClarke This doesn't build the menu. That still happens separately.  I'll update my answer to provide more detail